# What is the proper way to make a worthy post?

Tags: support

I am not familiar with StackOverflow. It seem like there is always someone who doesn't like my question, regardless of how careful or polite I formulated the question. I am not the kind of person who unload my homework on other people carelessly. I asked because I couldn't find an answer through various searches.

However, the answer should be easy for the experts in the field. Some of these experts, instead of a short answer, preferred instead a longer post with no answer but a lecture that I should search the answer by myself.

What are the guidelines to start a post on StackOverflow? Thanks,

Comment: The guidelines for everything you do on SO are all listed in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Are you referring to [this downvoted question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27574071/139010) or is there another example you have in mind?

Comment: @Matt Ball yes, exactly, and the question I asked 2 days ago. From my point of view (I don't know the answer). I prepare the question so that people know that I had already worked on it. 
However, from the experts (who know the answer in a flash), the question looks useless. I participate in an online course forum too (Coursera) and I know how annoying are the irresponsible questions. I always ignore them. NEVER I will waste any time to answer, just to lecture someone. As such, I always make sure my Qs are responsible. But somehow, on SO, that seems to always ruffle someone the wrong way.

Comment: @iCodez That's all there is as recommendation (in Help Center)? I think I have full-fillled as the criteria as a responsible SO citizen.

Comment: We expect a lot of research: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/139010 – Stack Exchange is not a substitute for independent research via Google (or pick-your-favorite-search-engine). Did you try searching first?

Comment: You said *"What are the guidelines to start a post on StackOverflow?"*.  I was showing you where they are.  If you follow them all, then there is no reason why your question will not be well received.  Repeating the guidelines here really serves no purpose IMO.

Comment: @MattBall, Thanks for the link about the personal research efforts. I'll do better next time. Now I think I may have mis-used SO resources with my easy-to-answer question. I thought of SO as a kind of forum/blogs.

Comment: First, Google, Then Google, Next try Google,finally, Google once more.  2nd hit out of 49 Million for `r modulo` was [this one](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html).  Then when you are defeated, carefully compose an SO post.

Answer (score 4):

I looked through your downvoted questions.

---

## [Is there a Modulo operator in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574071/is-there-a-modulo-operator-in-r)

I don’t think this is an altogether bad question. You clearly have tried something and provided the code you tried. I personally wouldn’t upvote it, but I don’t think it deserves a downvote either.

That said, I was able to find the answer with a little searching. I’m not sure what query you were using, but when I searched DuckDuckGo with the query <kbd>R modulus</kbd>, the fourth result was a message on the R-help mailing list asking whether such an operator existed. The second reply included the answer, `%%`.

---

## [Python script to insert thousand separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669438/python-script-to-insert-thousand-separator)

This one is a little more problematic. You have described what you’re trying to do, but I don’t see an attempt at a solution. You have this plea in your question:

> I could do the job easily in other languages. But for this exercise, I need a Python script. Please help me to write a script ready for use. Sorry if this sounds like a careless request. I do know programming, the trouble here is that I don't know anything about Python.

Okay, maybe I’m a little sympathetic, but that doesn’t change the standards of questions on Stack Overflow. It may be a little daunting trying to learn a new language and perform a task, but it’s not really appropriate to ask for a full solution here. It may help to break the problem down. You say you had experience in other programming languages, so you might figure out the general flow that applies to implementations in nearly any language:

- Get a command line argument.
- Parse the command line argument into a float.
- Format the float with a thousands separator.
- Print a string.

Or something like that, at least. Then you could look into each of the steps individually, for which you might find documentation or other resources online, or you might have to ask a question for.

---

## General tips

I was thinking about linking to [Jon Skeet’s reference](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) on writing a good question, but skimming through the headings and a little bit of the text there, I think you’ve done a reasonable job on those fronts. I think what users here are looking for in those questions is a little more research. A lot of your questions have been well-received, though, and you should be proud of that. You might consider looking for differences between the well-received and not-so-well-received questions you’ve asked, and trying to make your future questions (and possibly editing your downvoted questions) more like the well-received ones.

Comment: I searched by "R modulo operator" but somehow I couldn't find. The "R modulus" you suggested however did a hit. It's true that I should think about modulus rather than modulo. But well, now if you do "R modulo"  on SO, my Q above, unfortunately will be the one that show up first. The question about the Python script, yes that was the time I learnt that in SO, we don't mess up with unresponsible question. Never I will do such a thing again on SO. Strange that it is still there, I thought I deleted it.